# Refactor Jquery for Cookie Acceptance Message

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jquery.cookie.js, I wanted to share my code so if people have comments on how to make it more concise - better practices etc? I could learn.

The functionality is that a message appears, advising visitor of the use of cookies with an 'Ok' button to hide the message. Clicking Ok will set a cookie so that the user is not prompted again, whilst it is present.

.cc-cookie-accept is the class for the 'Ok' (accept) anchor button.
#cookie_loc is the Id of the DIV that contains the entire cookie message.

```
function hideCookieMsg(){
    $('#cookie_loc').hide();
};

function setCookie(){
    $.cookie("accept-cookies", "true", { expires: 365 });
};

function checkCookie(){
    if ($.cookie("accept-cookies")){
        return true;
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (checkCookie()){
        hideCookieMsg();
    }
});

$('.cc-cookie-accept').click(function() {
    hideCookieMsg();
    setCookie();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Went with this in the end, feel free to add comment.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       cookieMsgVisibility(!$.cookie("accept-cookies"));
});

function cookieMsgVisibility(doShow){
       $('#cookie_loc').toggle(doShow);
       if (doShow) {
            $('.cc-cookie-accept').click(function() {
            $.cookie("accept-cookies", "true", {
                  expires : 365
           });
           cookieMsgVisibility(false);
        });
       }
}
```